# How to fill shapes with color gradient in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to fill shapes with colors gradient corresponding to a continuous variable. I don't have any errors, but it does not print on the graph.

I tried to use `as.numeric` to make sure the variable is continuous.

## The NMDS is already calculated and it works. Everything works except the color gradient.

```
ggplot()+ 
        geom_point(data = NMDS.all.taxa, aes(y = NMDS2, x = NMDS1, fill = env$elev.num), shape = env$saison, size = 4)+ #this is the points
        geom_path(data = df_ell.all.taxa, aes(x = NMDS1, y = NMDS2, colour = group))+     ##Elipses
        scale_fill_gradient2(low = "green", mid = "blue", high = "red", midpoint = 1800)+   ##fill
        theme_bw()+
        theme(panel.background = element_blank(), 
              panel.grid.major = element_blank(),  #remove major-grid labels
              panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),  #remove minor-grid labels
              plot.background = element_blank() 
        )
```

It gives me a NMDS with everything except that the shapes are empty. Not any Error codes.

To recreate aspects of the data:

```
library(vegan)
Macro_AUG_2019_rep.<- matrix(0:10, ncol = 20, nrow = 50) 
env <- data.frame(Traitement = sample(c("n","r"),50, replace = TRUE), 
                  saison = sample(c("S","A"),50, replace = TRUE),
                  Elevation = sample(1000:1049), 
                  Site = sample(c("lake1","lake2","lake3","lake4","lake5","lake6","lake7"), 
                                50, replace = TRUE))

spe.nmds <- metaMDS(Macro_AUG_2019_rep., distance='bray', k=2, try=999, maxit=500)
NMDS.all.taxa <- data.frame(NMDS1 = spe.nmds$points[,1],
                            NMDS2 = spe.nmds$points[,2], 
                            group = env$Traitement,
                            sites = env$Site)

veganCovEllipse <- function(cov, center = c(0, 0), scale = 1.75, npoints = 100) { 
  theta <- (0:npoints) * 2 * pi/npoints 
  Circle <- cbind(cos(theta), sin(theta)) 
  t(center + scale * t(Circle %*% chol(cov))) 
}

df_ell.all.taxa <- data.frame()
for(g in levels(NMDS.all.taxa$group)){ 
  df_ell.all.taxa <- rbind(
    df_ell.all.taxa, 
    cbind(as.data.frame(with(NMDS.all.taxa[NMDS.all.taxa$group == g, ], 
                             veganCovEllipse(cov.wt(cbind(NMDS1, NMDS2),
                                                    wt=rep(1 / length(NMDS1), 
                                                           length(NMDS1)))$cov,
                                             center=c(mean(NMDS1), mean(NMDS2))))),
          group = g)
  ) 
}
NMDS.mean.all.taxa = aggregate(NMDS.all.taxa[ ,c("NMDS1", "NMDS2")], 
                               list(group = NMDS.all.taxa$group), 
                               mean)
```

Comment: Care to provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: It is really difficult to figure out what is wrong when we don't have a reproducible example or illustration of the problem. If you don't want to share your data, that is fine, but could you then demonstrate the problem with a build-in dataset (iris for example). What type of variable is `env$saison`?

Comment: Here is a code to create data of the same type:

Comment: Macro_AUG_2019_rep.<- matrix(0:10, ncol = 20, nrow = 50)
env <- data.frame(
                  Traitement = sample(c("n","r"),50, replace = TRUE),
                  saison = sample(c("S","A"),50, replace = TRUE),
                  Elevation = sample(1000:1049),
                  Site = sample(c("lake1","lake2","lake3","lake4","lake5","lake6","lake7"), 
                  50, replace = TRUE)
                  )

Comment: Using vegan package, I than apply that code to the previous one :

Comment: spe.nmds <- metaMDS(Macro_AUG_2019_rep., distance='bray', k=2, try=999, maxit=500)
  
NMDS.all.taxa <- data.frame(NMDS1 = spe.nmds$points[,1], ##fait tableau avec coordonnees NMDS
                            NMDS2 = spe.nmds$points[,2], group = env$Traitement, ## groupes pour élipses
                            sites = env$Site)

###Plot NMDS avec élipses 
veganCovEllipse<-function (cov, center = c(0, 0), scale = 1.75, npoints = 100) 
{
  theta <- (0:npoints) * 2 * pi/npoints
  Circle <- cbind(cos(theta), sin(theta))
  t(center + scale * t(Circle %*% chol(cov)))
}

Comment: ###

df_ell.all.taxa <- data.frame()

for(g in levels(NMDS.all.taxa$group)){
  df_ell.all.taxa <- rbind(df_ell.all.taxa, cbind(as.data.frame(with(NMDS.all.taxa[NMDS.all.taxa$group==g,],
                                                                     veganCovEllipse(cov.wt(cbind(NMDS1,NMDS2),wt=rep(1/length(NMDS1),
                                                                                                                      length(NMDS1)))$cov,center=c(mean(NMDS1),mean(NMDS2))))),group=g))
}

Comment: # data for labelling the ellipse
NMDS.mean.all.taxa=aggregate(NMDS.all.taxa[ ,c("NMDS1", "NMDS2")], 
                             list(group = NMDS.all.taxa$group), mean)

Comment: And then I do the ggplot one. env$saison is factor. Thank you!

Comment: I took the liberty of formatting the code and appending it to your question for easier copy-pasting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ggplot2 doesn't play nice with `$` operators in `aes()` functions, so it would be good practise to avoid these by appending the `env$Elevation` and `env$saison` to your main `data.frame`:

```
df <- cbind(NMDS.all.taxa, Elevation = env$Elevation, Saison = env$saison)
```

Now, if I understood correctly, the problem was that the `geom_point` shapes aren't filled. The `shape` aesthetic in ggplot2 is (I think) identical to the `pch` argument in base R plots, so we can see what the values would mean:

[image]

Factor variables are integers dressed up with a level-label, so the `env$saison` that you were using would pass down `1`s and `2`s as shapes. These shapes are line-only, without any fill associated with them.

Thus, to fix the problem we need to let ggplot know what shapes we actually want, `21` and `24` for example. To map your factor variable to these shapes, we'll define the shapes inside the `aes()` function. Then, we can use `scale_shape_manual()` to set the correct shapes.

```
# I defined the xy mapping in the main `ggplot()` call so that we
# don't need to do this seperately for the path and points
ggplot(data = df, aes(NMDS1, NMDS2))+ 
  geom_point(aes(fill = Elevation, shape = Saison), 
             size = 4) +
  geom_path(data = df_ell.all.taxa, 
            aes(colour = group)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(21, 24)) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "green", mid = "blue", high = "red",
                       # I adjusted the midpoint to match example
                       midpoint = mean(df$Elevation))
```

Which gave me the following plot:

[image]

As an aside, your problem would have been easily illustrated with a build-in dataset. It is more in line with what a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) is, and it would have saved your time copying your data analysis code. Example below:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = Petal.Width), shape = iris$Species) +
  scale_fill_gradient()
```

To which the answer would have been:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = Petal.Width, shape = Species)) +
  scale_fill_gradient() +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(21, 22, 24))
```